# SWIFT 3 + UIButton Don't fire into UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a problem to access a `UIButton`.
This `UIButton` is inside a file called *UITableViewCell.xib*

In this file there are `UIButton`, `UILabel` and `UIImageView`.

I can access the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` with no problem, but when I try to add action to the `UIButton` it appears to be disabled (when I tap on it, it does not flash as usual).

I am using the following code to access it:

**MainTableView**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell:mainTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! mainTableViewCell

    cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    cell.openMenu.addTarget(self,action:#selector(testPressed), for:.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}


func testPressed()
{
    print("actionMenu")
}
```

**MainTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class mainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var theImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var openMenu: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var loadingBar: UIProgressView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: On clicking button, did it go to testPressed function ?

Comment: are you sure that the button is not disabled form the interface builder?